# A9G GSM not connecting to teensy 4.0

Tags: gps, teensy

Below is my current code for connecting to the A9G. As far as I can tell, it never actually opens a connection as `HWSERIAL.println("AT");` does not return anything. Any ideas would be appreciated.

The TX and RX pins of the A9G connected to the 0 and 1 pins on the teensy

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    
    #define HWSERIAL Serial1
    
    void setup()
    {
      //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
      Serial.begin(115200);
      
      //Begin serial communication with Arduino and A6
      HWSERIAL.begin(115200);
    
      Serial.println("Initializing..."); 
      delay(1000);
    
      HWSERIAL.println("AT"); //Once the handshake test is successful, it will back to OK
      updateSerial();
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
      updateSerial();
    }
    
    void updateSerial()
    {
      delay(500);
      while (Serial.available()) 
      {
        HWSERIAL.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
      }
      while(HWSERIAL.available()) 
      {
        Serial.write(HWSERIAL.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
      }
    }
```

Comment: you said nothing about the connections, so there may be none

Comment: I've got the TX and RX pins of the A9G connected to the 0 and 1 pins on the teensy

Comment: What voltage did you use to power the A9G module? Most GSM modules need something higher than 3.5V for their radio stage. Doublecheck the module datasheet.

Comment: @ChrisH its running on 5v